# UART transfer speed

Tags: communication, uart, data-transfer

I want to check if my understanding is correct, however I cannot find any precise explanation or examples. Let's say I have UART communication set to 57600 bits/second and I am transferring 8 bit chars. Let's say I choose to have no parity and since I need one start bit and one stop bit, that means that essentially for transferring one char I would need to transfer 10 bits. Does that mean that the transfer speed would be 5760 chars/second?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is essentially correct.
But the 5760 chars/second would be the maximum transfer rate.  Since it's an asynchronous link, the UART transmitter is allowed to idle the line between character frames.

IOW the baud rate only applies to the bits of the character frame.
The rate that characters are transmitted depends on whether there is data available to keep the transmitter busy/saturated.
For instance, if a microcontroller used programmed I/O (with either polling or interrupt) instead of DMA for UART transmiting, high-priority interrupts could stall the transmissions and introduce delays between frames.

Answer (score 0):

```
Baudrate                     = 57600

Time for 1 Bit: 1 / 57600    = 17,36 us

Time for a frame with 10 Bit = 173,6 us

this means max. 1 / 1736 us  = 5760 frames(characters) / s**
```